# How to change default date,timestamp dataype for columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp, sqldatatypes

I have created a table in Oracle in which I have `KPI_START_DATE` column which is a Date datatype, and `KPI_START_TIME` which is a `TIMESTAMP` datatype. 
Now I want to modify this date dataype for

`KPI_START_DATE` to `dd/mm/yyyy`

and

`KPI_START_TIME` to `HH:MI:SS`.

So that user should always enter the date and time in this column in this proper format.

I tried below query but its was giving error:

```
Alter table KPI_DEFINITION MODIFY(to_char(KPI_START_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy') )
```

Comment: One of the many great things about Oracle is that is has very early on undertood that date and time formats should not be confused with data itself. It has "solved" that problem by NOT storing any date or time in a user format, but to use a mathematical value instead. Actually, one that is more precise as the value it shows, but that is something else. Important to know is : Oracle ONLY uses format for display, NOT for storage. It does NOT store formats of dates or hours. - And if you think about storing time and dates as CHAR or VARCHAR2 : do NOT even think about it!

Answer (score 4):

[DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref152) and [TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i53219) columns do not have any inherent readable format. The values are stored in Oracle's own internal representation, which has no resemblance to a human-readable date or time. At the point to retrieve or display a value you can convert it to whatever format you want, with `to_char()`.

Both DATE and TIMESTAMP have date and time components (to second precision with DATE, and with fractional seconds with TIMESTAMP; plus time zone information with the extended data types), and you should not try to store them separately as two columns. Have a single column and extract the information you need at any time; to get the information out of a single column but split into two fields you could do:

```
select to_char(KPI_START, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as KPI_START_DATE,
  to_char(KPI_START, 'hh24:mi:ss') as KPI_START_TIME
```

but you'd generally want both together anyway:

```
select to_char(KPI_START, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Also notice the 'hh24' format model to get the 24-hour clock time; otherwise you wouldn't see any difference between 3 a.m. and 3 p.m.

You can store a value in either type of column with the time set to midnight, but it does still have a time component - it is just midnight. You can't store a value in either type of column with just a time component - it has to have a date too. You could make that a nominal date and just ignore it, but I've never seen a valid reason to do that - you're wasting storage in two columns, and making searching for and comparing values much harder. Oracle even provides a default date if you don't specify one (first day of current month). But the value always has both a date and a time part:

```
create table KPI_DEFINITION (KPI_START date);
insert into KPI_DEFINITION (KPI_START)
  values (to_date('27/01/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
insert into KPI_DEFINITION (KPI_START)
  values (to_date('12:41:57', 'HH24:MI:SS'));
select to_char(KPI_START, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from KPI_DEFINITION;

TO_CHAR(KPI_START,'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS')
-----------------------------------------
2015-01-27 00:00:00                       
2015-01-01 12:41:57
```

Your users should be inserting a single value with both date and time as one:

```
insert into KPI_DEFINITION (KPI_START)
  values (to_date('27/01/2015 12:41:57', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
select to_char(KPI_START, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from KPI_DEFINITION;

TO_CHAR(KPI_START,'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS')
-----------------------------------------
2015-01-27 12:41:57
```

You can also use [date or timestamp literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17118/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ), and if using `to_date()` you should always specify the full format - don't rely on NLS settings as they may be different for other users.

Comment: In date datatype of oracle it store both date and time. I dont want that. I want only in date datatype it should enter date while in timestamp it should enter time. for example :create table t1
   ( flight_date date,
     flight_time as (to_char(flight_date,'HH24:SS:MI')),
     flight_day as (to_char(flight_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'))
   );

Comment: Is it not possible to insert only date in date datatype and time in timestamp ? Are there any datatype in oracle which is useful for this ? This is important when user enter values in this columns ...I dont want them to insert anything .

Comment: @ajay - you can store a DATE with a time set to midnight; that's the closest to a date with no time, but it's important to realise that it still does have a time component. And you can't have a DATE or a TIMESTAMP with *just* a time component, it has to have a valid date. You could use a nominal date and ignore it later, or use an INTERVAL I guess. But you'd need a really good reason to store the two parts separately anyway, and I don't think I've ever seen one. It makes comparison harder and I don't see any advantage of doing so. Your users should be inserting a full datetime into one column.

Answer (score 3):

You should understand difference between *datatype* and *format*. DATE is a datatype. TIMESTAMP is a datatype. None of them have formats, they're just numbers.

When converting character datatype to or from date datatype, format should be applied. It's an attribute of an actual conversion, nothing else.

Look at this:

```
SQL> create table tmp$date(d date);

Table created

SQL> insert into tmp$date values (DATE '2010-11-01');

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into tmp$date values (DATE '2014-12-28');

1 row inserted

SQL> select d, dump(d) from tmp$date;

D           DUMP(D)
----------- ---------------------------------
01.11.2010  Typ=12 Len=7: 120,110,11,1,1,1,1
28.12.2014  Typ=12 Len=7: 120,114,12,28,1,1,1
```

There is no any 'format' here.

Comment: In date datatype of oracle it store both date and time. I dont want that. I want only in date datatype it should enter date while in timestamp it should enter time. for example :create table t1
   ( flight_date date,
     flight_time as (to_char(flight_date,'HH24:SS:MI')),
     flight_day as (to_char(flight_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'))
   );

Comment: Is it not possible to insert only date in date datatype and time in timestamp ? Are there any datatype in oracle which is useful for this ? This is important when user enter values in this columns ...I dont want them to insert anything .

Comment: Anything is possible. But when you wish, say, to store intergal part of a number into one variable while fractional part of this number into another, you should not wonder if it looks poorly supported, comfortless and absurd.

Comment: thanks man :) you are right its not possible in oracle to set such formats :)

Answer (score 1):

**DISPLAYING** and **STORING** are **NOT** the same when it comes to **DATE**.

When people say Oracle isn’t storing the date in the format they wanted, what is really happening is Oracle is not presenting the date in the character string format they expected or wanted.

When a data element of type DATE is selected, it must be converted from its internal, binary format, to a string of characters for human consumption. The conversion of data from one type to another is known as known a **“conversion”**, “type casting” or “coercion”. In Oracle the conversion between dates and character strings is controlled by the **NLS_DATE_FORMAT** model. The NLS_DATE_FORMAT can be set in any of several different locations, each with its own scope of influence.

I could go on with my leacture over DATE data type, but I am glad that someone has already got a good writeup over this. Please read this https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/